# How to show a 'running total' of test successes and failures in maven?

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have a bunch of `JUnit` tests I'm running with maven using the following `plugin`:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.17</version>
```

When I run them, they take about 20 minutes to run. Sometimes a test 2 minutes in will fail, but the whole thing will keep running.

I'd like to kill it as soon as I know a test has failed.

My question is: **How to show a 'running total' of test successes and failures in maven?**

Comment: First how many tests are you running? Are you running from Eclipse/IntelliJ or from Console?

Comment: Caution: There is a bug in surefire that causes that if you interrupt maven process, surefire test runner is still running as a separate process.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923857/is-there-a-way-to-fail-fast-for-junit-with-the-maven-surefire-plugin

Comment: Are you aware of [`RunListener`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html)s? You can write a class that will listen and do some logic at the beginning and end of each test; you could use that to log the current test count for example. Also, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968475/using-junit-runlistener-with-maven)