# How to see test-by-test stdout/stderr in Maven surefire

Tags: java, maven, junit

I run a JUnit-based test suite in Maven, some 200 tests in total.  Many produce Log4J DEBUG or ERROR lines, and I see them all mashed into a single long file in my surefire-reports directory.

I want to see all this output divided up by test, so I can discover what test produced what output.  How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using JUnit RunListener with Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968475/using-junit-runlistener-with-maven)

Comment: The question I just referenced as a duplicate explains how to use `RunListener`s to do what you want in surefire.

Comment: This is indeed what I would like, but it seems like it should be do-able without any custom coding? We use Teamcity as a CI server, and when the tests fail there I can click on a test and see ONLY that test's output. I would like the equivalent when running Maven on the command line too.  Is there no surefire  configuration that achieves this?

Comment: I don't think surefire has a way to do this without writting a little code. The `RunListener` can be very simple, it should be less than a dozen lines of code, about 30 lines if you include the maven configuration changes.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward solution would be to a call to the following method to the beginning and end of each test:

```
static void printBeginning(PrintStream stream) {
  String methodName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
  stream.format("---- Beginning Test: %s ----%n", methodName);
}
```

---

However, if you want to use surefire, the way to do this would be to write your own custom [RunListener](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html):

Basically, assign the RunListener in Maven, as in [this documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html)

```
<plugins>
[...]
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <properties>
        <property>
          <name>listener</name>
          <value>com.mycompany.MyResultListener,com.mycompany.MyResultListener2</value>
        </property>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
[...]
</plugins>
```

Then the code will be run by Surefire.

You can read more about how to do this here: [Using JUnit RunListener with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968475/using-junit-runlistener-with-maven)

Comment: To be clear, this is actually Log4J debug statements, which I turn on to help better diagnose why tests fail when they do fail. Also, I was looking for some kind of surefire configuration to do this - I already know various ways to accomplish this in JUnit including the brute force method you suggest.

Comment: it does not really pertain to the issue at hand, but I edited it as requested so we can focus on the actual question.