# How to capture the Junit Test Result of Project in Database

Tags: jenkins, junit, testng, jenkins-plugins

We have lots of independent module(lets say X) and all the X modules have either

1. Junit Test Cases
2. TestNG

The test cases execute whenever a developer builds the module using Jenkins. I am constructing a UI dashboard to show the test case result for every module. In this dashboard I will be showing lots of other things. So, the result of Test Cases will be just a column.

**Problem**: I need a tool/plugin by which I should be able to save the junit results in database, the moment it is build via jenkins. Is it possible or do I need to write my own java program?

Comment: I am more of a build guy..lets say that I can not touch the Junit/TestNg code of other modules. I can provide them some guidelines with justification at max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by implementing `org.testng.IReporter`.

IReporter interface has only one method:

```
public void generateReport(List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory)
```

This method will be invoked by TestNG when all the suites have been run. 
The another alternate is implementing Interface `ITestListener` listener or extend `TestListenerAdapter`.

```
public class MyTestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {
    //do the needful
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult tr) {
    //do the needful
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult tr) {
    //do the needful
  }
```

You can refer [TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there isn't any plugin or similar.

You have to implement it on your own. In case of JUnit you can implement a [TestWatcher](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Rules#testwatchmantestwatcher-rules):

```
@Rule
public TestWatcher watchman = new TestWatcher() {

    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
        // Store result in DB
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded(Description description) {
        // Store result in DB
    }
};
```

https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2015/09/14/the-art-of-test-driven-development-logging-junit-test-results/

#### Don't want to use a @Rule

If you don't want to change every test, you should have a look for the [RunListener](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html).

`testStarted(Description description)` and `testFinished(Description description)` are the methods to implement.

With maven you can use the surefire plugin, but [it have to be 2.7 or newer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5204917/390177).

Comment: thats a very good example..but I can not implement it on my own:-( I dont have the liberty to write/modify test cases of other modules.

Comment: @vivek081141 Updated my answer.